# Can't connect to network: emulator eclipse

Tags: android, emulation

I have tried next to solve the problem:

- to change Mobile Networks settings;
- set Editional emulator command line settings;

but still can't get connection to network.

Eclipce 4.2
Android 4.2.2

Please help.

Comment: Who cannot get connection to which network?

Comment: Android emulator has no connection to network. We use proxy for connection. But I don't know how to set it for emulator.

Comment: This does not help you? https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=android+emulator+behind+proxy

Comment: Then why is your case different from all the ones found by google? You could tell a little bit more if you still want help. No you don't have to tell a little bit more. You have to tell a lot more.

Comment: I am new in IT, it is difficult for me to explain you all details. But I'll try. OS: Win7x64. We use proxy for network connection(but there is no IP of proxy server, we use something like "domen" instead of it - I don't not why!) I have tried to

Comment: Connectiong to a network is one. Your device in this case the emulator has to do that. Connecting to a server is two. Your app has to do so. What info do you see in the LogCat?

Comment: The main problem is that I need to connect my application, that is installed on emulator, to the network. I didn't craete eclipse project, I have just tried to launch emulator (Android 4.2.2) with changing Mobile Networks settings with our settings(only 2 parameters: "domen" on our proxy and port), it didn't help.

Comment: Then I have tried to set same settings in Editional emulator command line settings, but it also didn't help. I don't understand why we use alias for proxy, may be the problem is in it?!

Comment: `The main problem is that I need to connect my application, that is installed on emulator, to the network.` No. I just told you that there were two things.

Comment: By the way: i wouldn't know how to install an .apk on an emulator if i could not use Eclipse or a network. How did you manage? By the way 2: You mention Eclipse 4.2 in this post. Then why?

Comment: Answer about LogCat: I don't know what is it, but I have found how to open it, unfortunately it didn't show any information, after launching emulator and attempting to connect to the network.

Comment: Answer for Installation of apk: I use next command "adb install path to apk" in cmd. Installation was successful.

Comment: U know I'm sorry all is OK now. I have reinsatlled new version of apk, and it can connect to the server, but still no connection to the network, I also need it, but it wasn't  priority task.

Comment: ????? How can your app have connection to a (web)server while there is not a connection to a network? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I don't know, but I think that network should be configured separatly. Now the application is sending requests to the server, and it is geting the responses. Realy I don't know why, have you any suppositions?

Comment: Hmmm.. then if you don't know .. i i don't know how you cannot have connection to a network now... and you do need connection to a network on your way... then please tell me what does not funcion now.. for what do you need it?

Comment: I need it for registration in order to use application. Registration is made using default mobile browser.

Comment: Then tell me why the browser on the emulator has no access and your app has.

Comment: May be because server is local, access to network needs proxy settings, and I can't configure it in a right way?

Comment: `because server is local,` and why didn't you tell that right away?

Comment: Sorry, I recognize it only now. Can you help me to configure network?

Comment: Sorry. Don't think so. I gave you a link already.

Comment: I have tried it and of course I have already searched it before. As I had written we use proxy for network connection(but there is no IP of proxy server, we use something like "domen" instead of it), so while connection I use this "doment" and port, but it didn't work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61408/discussion-on-question-by-ekaterina-poligon-cant-connect-to-network-emulator-e).